# How do you get a VPC Endpoint to work in a Docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm not able to get the AWS CLI to download a text file from S3 in a Docker container. There is a VPC setup with a VPC Endpoint approved on the S3 policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::secret-store/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": " DenyUnEncryptedInflightOperations",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::secret-store/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::secret-store/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-de7893b7"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using a Dockerfile that installs the AWS CLI and calls an entrypoint script:

```
FROM java:8
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install python curl unzip && cd /tmp && \
    curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" \
    -o "awscli-bundle.zip" && \
    unzip awscli-bundle.zip && \
    ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws && \
    rm awscli-bundle.zip && rm -rf awscli-bundle

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The entrypoint script sets the AWS CLI config file and calls `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file.txt -`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir ~/.aws

echo '[default]
aws_access_key_id=
aws_secret_access_key=
output=json
region=us-west-2' > ~/.aws/config

aws --version

aws s3 cp s3://secret-store/test.txt -
```

When I run the entrypoint script from the EC2 CLI, I get the expected authorized response:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-86 ~]$ ./entrypoint.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/ec2-user/.aws’: File exists
aws-cli/1.11.22 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.4.79
Hello secure VPC world!
```

But I get a `download failed (Forbidden)` error when I run the same script from a Docker image on the same host that it was successful:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-86 ~]$ docker build . -t test && docker run test
Sending build context to Docker daemon 15.89 MB
Step 1 : FROM java:8
 ---> 861e95c114d6
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install python curl unzip && cd /tmp &&     curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip"     -o "awscli-bundle.zip" &&     unzip awscli-bundle.zip &&     ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws &&     rm awscli-bundle.zip && rm -rf awscli-bundle
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c948b9caeaae
Step 3 : COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c1774cc5d57
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 98179b1b7172
 ---> d8f12456a198
Removing intermediate container 98179b1b7172
Successfully built d8f12456a198
aws-cli/1.11.22 Python/2.7.9 Linux/3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.4.79
download failed: s3://secret-store/test.txt to - An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Anyone know why I'm getting a Forbidden response in a docker container that is running on the same host I'm getting a success response from?

Answer (score 0):

VPC Endpoints use internal addresses, so if your build container is resolving the external s3 endpoint the policy won't apply. Docker build should just use the bridge network but you could add an nslookup debug line to your Dockerfile and compare to the same command on the host where it works.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit how exactly to solve this problem (no access to s3-endpoint from inside the container)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a VPC endpoint for S3 you need an endpoint policy to allow access to the S3 buckets that docker hub uses.

I.e.:

```
{
    "Version": "...",
    "Id": "...",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "stmtAllowDockerImages",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::docker-images-prod",
                "arn:aws:s3:::docker-images-prod/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```